# Placing Critters in the appropriate place in the Natural Order Hierarchy in Mouse Guard

Tags: balance, mouse-guard, mouse-guard-2e

I am currently developing a campaign setting using the rules and lore for Mouse Guard. The setting will be similar but not in the same geographical location (Northern Michigan) that the original was written in. To that end I will be bringing in additional animals and developing their stats.  I asked a question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165040/balancing-new-critters-in-mouse-guard) that references how to balance the Nature scores and encounter abilities of the creatures but will also need to determine how best to place new creatures in the Natural Order table.

In MG mice can only directly attack/kill creatures that are up to two levels higher than they are in the hierarchy.  Where to place a new creature in this table could indicate mechanically whether they would need extraordinary means to interact with that creature during an encounter.  Balancing this would be an important part of creating a new creature in a custom Mouse Guard campaign.

I'm looking for expertise in balancing new creatures and placing them within the Natural Order hierarchy when introducing them into a Mouse Guard campaign.

I'm looking for answers using the "Good Subjective" standard and **experience on how specifically balancing was done and determining where to place the creatures in the *Natural Order* hierarchy.**